# How to update the vuex state from component 'A' and it should reflect on component 'B'

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have two Components 'A' and 'B' both using the same state But both Components are on different pages. I want to update the state from 'A' and it should reflect on 'B'?

example:

Component 'A'

```js
<template>
   <div>{{value}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'A',
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateState'])
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['value'])
  }
</script>
```

Component 'B'

```js
<template>
  <div> {{value}} </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'B',
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['value'])
  }
</script>
```

Store

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    value: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_STATE(state,value){
       state.value = value
    }
  },
 actions: {
    updateState({commit},value){
      commit('UPDATE_STATE',value)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

On your component A, you just need to call the action by `this.updateState` (or `updateState` if from template)

from template:

```html
<button @click="updateState('New Value')">Update</button>
```

from methods:

```js
export default {
  name: 'A',
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateState']),
    updateStoreState() {
        this.updateState("New Value");
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['value'])
  }
}
```